Python decryption function not producing expected output
I'm implementing a password decryption function in Python, but I'm having trouble getting the expected output. The function is supposed to apply alternating rotation values to characters based on their index and handle vowels by surrounding them with 0s.
Here's my code:
def decrypt_password(password: str) -> str:
    rot7, rot9 = 7, 9  # Rotation values
    vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou'  # Vowels to check
    decrypted = []  # List to hold decrypted characters

    for index, char in enumerate(password):
        if char in vowels:
            rotation_key = rot9 if index % 2 == 1 else rot7  # Use 9 for odd indices
            decrypted.append('0')  # Add '0' before the vowel
        else:
            rotation_key = rot7 if index % 2 == 0 else rot9  # Use 7 for even indices

        if 33 <= ord(char) <= 126:  # Check if character is within the allowed ASCII range
            decrypted_char = chr((ord(char) - rotation_key - 33) % 94 + 33)  # Wrap around
            decrypted.append(decrypted_char)  # Add decrypted character to the list
        else:
            decrypted.append(char)  # Append unchanged if out of range

        if char in vowels:
            decrypted.append('0')  # Add '0' after the vowel

    return ''.join(decrypted)  # Join the list into a string and return

# Test case
print(decrypt_password("bAnanASplit")) 

Expected output:
"i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{".

Actual output:
"0b0'C'0n0'c'0n0'C'Spl'k't".

I've tried adding print statements to track the character transformations, but I'm still getting incorrect results.
Environment: Python 3.12.

The only change you need is to use + rotation_key instead of - rotation_key.

Just a suggestion: Try to find a video tutorial that shows how to step through Python code with a debugger. That should quickly allow you to find the place things go wrong. Also, extract a [mcve], which means the smallest amount of code including the smallest possible hardcoded data that shows the issue. Your example input is way to large, I believe.

def decrypt_password(password: str) -> str:
    rot7, rot9 = 7, 9  # Rotation values
    decrypted = []  # List to hold decrypted characters
    vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou'
    for index, char in enumerate(password):
        rotation_key = rot9 if index % 2 == 1 else rot7  # Use 9 for odd indices
        decrypted_char = char
        if 33 <= ord(char) <= 126:  # Check if character is within the allowed ASCII range
            decrypted_char = chr(((ord(char) + rotation_key) - 33) % 93 + 33)  # Make sure the char range is between 33 and 126
        if char in vowels: # if vowels, add preceding and succeeding zero
            decrypted_char = '0' + decrypted_char + '0'
        decrypted.append(decrypted_char)
    return ''.join(decrypted)  # Join the list into a string and return


print(decrypt_password('bAnanASplit'))
print(decrypt_password('bEaUtY'))
print(decrypt_password('bEauTy'))
print(decrypt_password('cAlZonE'))

Outputs:
i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{
i0N00h00^0{b
i0N00h00!0[%
j0J0sc0v0w0L0

As expected.

Hi! Thank you so much for your help, it means a lot. I did as you recommended but the output is still not producing the expected message. im gonna leave the whole code down here so that you can see the whole picture.

Here's a link to a repo I created, I uploaded the file there but I think you can access through the code. Once again, thank you for your help.                                                https://github.com/Misalix/credential-checker/blob/main/Lab2.py

@miali2 can you share with me the full description of your task?

the description is too long to post here, I pasted it on Github gist, here's a link: https://gist.github.com/Misalix/b1785bed8307c67bc63d0e099fd290a0

@miali2 I edited my code and it passed all tests. You can check it for details.

Quick question, im very new to all this, when you were running the code, how did you do it? Im using pycharm and run the code there but it gives unexpected output. Btw thank you so much, I really appreciate your help :).

@miali2 by PyCharm too.

@miali2 I run my code in online Python environment, it gives the same output: https://ideone.com/pSVIpP

this is the output I'm receiving - "i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{
i0N00h00^0{b
i0N00h00!0[%
j0J0sc0v0w0L0
Formatted Username: Chevy_Chase
Decrypted Password: 0p09Q90|09q90|09Q9a%z9y9%
Authentication failed. Program exits...
"

As you can see when I put in the credentials "Chevy Chase i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{", The authentication fails and it even gives wrong decryption of the password

From the description 'Chevy_Chase': 'i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{', # cipher: bAnanASplit , it is the same as my output @miali2

okay but how did you make it to give that output, I can't seem to make it work and it's really frustrating.

You may want to explicitly mention what you changed, so readers don't have to mentally diff the code.
